# Regexp javascript and replace

Tags: javascript, regex, str-replace

When I test my regex online (like http://regex101.com), everything works fine. But when I test it in javascript, It doesn't. I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

```
var input = 'fzef zef zef zef (,  ) dezdezfzef  ezf ze';
input = input.replace('/\(\,?\s{0,}?\)/g', '');
console.log(input);
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the quotes from around your regex:

```
input.replace(/\(\,?\s{0,}?\)/g, '')
```